# Chrome Desktop sync error: "Corruption block checksum mismatch Failed"

Tags: google-chrome, sync

When I open chrome://sync-internals/ I saw red errors. One of them is:

> Preferences   52  52  Error:
> WriteModifications@components\sync\model\model_type_store_backend.cc:237,
> datatype error was encountered: Corruption: block checksum
> mismatch  Failed

How can I fix it without reseting?

jSon output

```
{
      "message": "Error: WriteModifications@components\\sync\\model\\model_type_store_backend.cc:237, datatype error was encountered: Corruption: block checksum mismatch",
      "name": "Preferences",
      "state": "Failed",
      "status": "severity_error",
      "num_entries": 52,
      "num_live": 52
}
```

Comment: Which Windows version? There were report that removing `Login Data` and `Login Data-journal` in the profile solves the problem: [link1](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9947763/error-syncing-passwords?hl=en) and [link2](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/49141991/chrome-password-sync-fails-intermittently-usually-on-chrome-upgrade?hl=en).